# Autocomplete in a ComboBox Using Access 2017

Tags: c#, ms-access, combobox, autocomplete

I want to make Autocomplete in a ComboBox using Access 2017. So I used this code... But there are some errors, like:

> "The name 'da' does not exist in the current context".

Please help me to fix this error.

```
    private void Autocomplete()
    {
        string query;
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Neth1.accdb");
        //opening connection
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            //initialize a new instance of sqlcommand
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            //set a connection used by this instance of sqlcommand
            cmd.Connection = con;
            //set the sql statement to execute at the data source
            cmd.CommandText = query;

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            //set the sql statement or stored procedure to execute at the data source
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            //initialize a new instance of DataTable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //add or resfresh rows in the certain range in the datatable to match those in the data source.
            da.Fill(dt);


            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                //getting all rows in the specific field|Column
                var rw = r.Field<string>("IMEI");


                //Set the properties of a combobox to make it auto suggest.
                comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                //adding all rows into the combobox
                comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(rw);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //catching error 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        //release all resources used by the component
          da.Dispose(); 
        //clossing connection
        con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your OleDbDataAdapter is declare inside the `try` block, it doesn't exist outside of it, hence the error you're seeing.
The `query` string presented here is empty.

When you deal with OleDb objects, it's common practice to make use
of `using` blocks, which take care of disposing the disposable objects you create.

What you rally don't want, is to set those controls properties inside a `foreach` loop.
It is also more efficient to fill the ComboBox AutoCompleteCustomSource using `AddRage()`, instead of adding objects one by one.

This is how I propose to edit your code:

```
// You can set these properties in the Form designer
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
// [...]

string query = "SELECT [Some Field] FROM [Some Table] WHERE [Some Condition]";
List<string> data = new List<string>();

try {
    using (var con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Neth1.accdb"))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con))  
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
            if (reader.HasRows) {
                while (reader.Read()) {
                   data.Add((string)reader["IMEI"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch {
    // Notify, log, whatever fits
}
 comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear();
 comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(data.ToArray());
 data.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();` is within try { } scope and

`da.Dispose();` is outside of that scope, try to place this line within try { } scope or move `OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();` outside of try { }scope.